# Counter issue vba

Tags: vba, excel

STILL really bad at vba....

1) I am trying to count the number of overdue tasks. At the moment it is not counting.

2) when i press f5 even though I have erased all the info in the page it goes to the next column 
eg If i erased column 1 it will go to column 2 even though there is no info in column 1.

```
Sub data_input_overdue()

    Dim rw As Long
    Dim Counter As Long

    Dim col As Long
    col = CountMyCols("Stats")

    Worksheets("Stats").Cells(2, col + 1).Value = "Overdue"

    Counter = 0


    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

        For i = 2 To CountMyRows(sht.Name)
            c_date = Range("E" & i)
            dueDate = CDate(c_date)
            If dueDate < Date And sht.Range("I" & i).Value = "No" Then
            Counter = Counter + CLng(1)
            Worksheets("Stats").Cells(i, col + 1).Value = Counter
        End If
        Next i
    Next sht
End Sub

Function CountMyCols(SName As String) As Long
    CountMyCols = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SName).UsedRange.Columns.Count
End Function
```

Comment: What is the value of `col`?  (I assume if you are writing to column 2 then it is `1`.)  Unless you meant `col` instead of `col + 1`, I suspect that your problem is not in the code you posted.

Comment: @YowE3K I edited

Comment: `UsedRange.Columns.Count` will never be 0.  Even if the worksheet is completely empty, cell A1 is deemed to be "used", therefore the count of used columns will be at least 1.  `1 + 1` will give `2`, which is why you are writing to column 2.   And `UsedRange.Columns.Count` doesn't tell you the last column used in your sheet anyway, e.g. if you create a new sheet and type something in cell H5 then `UsedRange.Columns.Count` will be 1, not 8.

Comment: @YowE3K Okay, right. Is there something else that i can change this to that will work?

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand what your code is attempting to do.  It appears that you are wanting to write some numbers to column A (but currently to B).  You first write a heading to row 2, then you loop through each worksheet writing a running count to the row in "Stats" if the row in the sheet being processed matches some criteria.  Then you potentially replace those numbers with the new counter when you process the next worksheet.  So if the first sheet contained 15 rows matching the criteria, and row 2 of the second sheet matched, you would write `16` to cell A2.  ?????

Comment: Um... So basically I have 30+ sheets and I am trying to sieve through the info to count the number of overdue tasks which I can find via column E using the counter then inputting this info to a master sheet with statistics ("Stats") 

But I am also counting the number of tasks on each page which will be in the column before the overdue tasks. So that's why it might be a bit confusing. sorry

Comment: OK - it's too early in the morning for me to think clearly (time I went and bought my morning coffee!) so I have placed an "answer" below showing a better way of determining which column is the last used one (and which returns zero if none are used).

Comment: I feel you! Thanks :) Hope you get your morning coffee soon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A replacement `CountMyCols` function might be:

```
Public Function CountMyCols(SName As String) As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SName)
        CountMyCols = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                                  After:=.Range("A1"), _
                                  Lookat:=xlPart, _
                                  LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                  SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                  MatchCase:=False).Column
    End With
End Function
```

This has been based on one of the examples in the now-retired StackOverflow Documentation:

```
Private Sub Get_Last_Used_Row_Index()
    Dim wS As Worksheet

    Set wS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Debug.Print LastCol_1(wS)
    Debug.Print LastCol_0(wS)
End Sub
```

You can choose between 2 options, regarding if you want to know if there is no data in the worksheet :

NO : Use LastCol_1 : You can use it directly within wS.Cells(...,LastCol_1(wS))

YES : Use LastCol_0 : You need to test if the result you get from the function is 0 or not before using it

```
Public Function LastCol_1(wS As Worksheet) As Double
    With wS
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            LastCol_1 = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                                After:=.Range("A1"), _
                                Lookat:=xlPart, _
                                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                MatchCase:=False).Column
        Else
            LastCol_1 = 1
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

The Err object's properties are automatically reset to zero upon function exit.

```
Public Function LastCol_0(wS As Worksheet) As Double
    On Error Resume Next
    LastCol_0 = wS.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=ws.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Column
End Function
```

Comment: Oh perfect! Thank you! that has solved one problem! its just the counter now!